Using localStorage to save the visibility state of an element in an Electron app using JSON and JS Literal Templates
Github Link: https://github.com/DavidKDean/D4Toolbox
I've been building an Electron app to show the locations of Altars of Lilith (Diablo 4) with in-game loctions and the in-game map. The elements are created through JS literal templates taken from JSON. The app starts with imgs I use as buttons to trigger an accordian effect that then reveals generated data from JSON that the user can then show/hide regions for.
I would like to allow the user to click a label (I'm using a checkbox that is hidden through CSS with the label allow the click function) to hide the element. I've tried everything I can to get localStorage to save this state - But for some reason I'm messing it up somewhere. I assume it is because I'm not working with the template correctly - But I can't figure out how to fire it off correctly.
I've got a dark/light mode in place that also uses the localStorage and it works fine.
This is my first post on SO so I'm not to sure how to go about this. I've got the project uploaded to Github if linking the project would be helpful.
Fractured Peaks Altars Template:
function fractPeaksAltarTemplate(altar) {
    return `
            <div class="altar-of-lilith-container" id="${altar.altarID}">

                <form id="altarCheckbox">
                    <div class="checkbox-container">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="altarButtonClass" id="${altar.altarDataID}">
                        <label for="${altar.altarDataID}" id="${altar.altarDataID}" onclick="${altar.onChecked}">${altar.name}</label>
                    </div>
                <form>

                <div id="${altar.name}" class="altarContainer">

                    <div>
                        <div id="altarImages">
                            <div class="altarImage">
                                <img class="smallImg" id="showMapImage" src="${altar.mapImage}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="altarImage">
                                <img class="smallImg" id="showInGameImage" src="${altar.inGameImage}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table-container">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Number</td>
                                <td>Region</td>
                                <td>Sub-Region</td>
                                <td>Area</td>
                                <td>Reward</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${altar.number}</td>
                                <td>${altar.region}</td>
                                <td>${altar.subregion}</td>
                                <td>${altar.area}</td>
                                <td>${altar.reward}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            `;
}

document.getElementById("fracturedPeaksLilithAltars").innerHTML = `${fractPeaksAltarDat.map(fractPeaksAltarTemplate).join('')}`;

First entry of JSON data:
Note: Just moved all Fractured Peaks data into 1 JS file to make it easier - Since there is going to be about 300 or so objects to these arrays.

const fractPeaksAltarDat = [
    {
        "number": "01",
        "name": "Desolate Highlands Altar of Lilith #1",
        "region": "Fractured Peaks",
        "subregion": "Desolate Highlands",
        "area": "Eastern Pass",
        "mapImage": "./img/altar-of-lilith/fractured-peaks/map/01-map.webp",
        "inGameImage": "./img/altar-of-lilith/fractured-peaks/in_game/01-in_game.webp",
        "reward": "+2 Dexterity",
        "altarID": "fractPeaksAltar01",
        "altarDataID": "fractPeaksAltarData01",
        "onChecked": "document.getElementById('fractPeaksAltar01').classList.toggle('hide')"
    }
];

I've tried:
electron-store,
electron-settings,
variants of "localStorage.setItem('checkbox', checked);"
I've used tutorials and examples from both SO and things like:
https://codepen.io/kylastoneberg/pen/qweppq
From the Image: In the red region is the label. When clicked the element will be hidden. Right now the status of being hidden isn't being saved in localStorage and when the app is closed and restarted - It returns.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/4Cb3KbLj.png

I don’t see altar.hideChecked defined in the data.

altar.hideChecked was an attempt at using the JSON data to "localStorage.setItem()" but it failed.
This was just a remnant of that attempt and I forgot to delete it from the onclick. I've since removed that (if you look at my Github). Just didn't notice it here.
Thanks for that.
Note: Github was linked in my profile - I've put a link to the project at the top of the question for ease.
